# Parser error at 2: syntax error, unexpected id, expecting $end

Tags: bison, yacc

I have a grammar file: It's a grammar for simple expressions.

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "../C_routines/SyntaxTree.h"
#define YYERROR_VERBOSE 1
extern int yylineno;

void yyerror(const char *s);
int i=0;
%}

%union {
    char *lexeme;
    char *value;
    double dvalue;
    struct SyntaxTree *Sy;
    int ivalue;
    char *op;
}

%type <Sy> E S
%token <lexeme> id ID 
%token <value> LITERAL
%token <dvalue> FLOAT
%token <ivalue> INT
%token <op> relop arith assign

%left '+' '-'
%left UMINUS

%%

S : id assign E { $$ = newOpNode($2, newIDNode($1), $3); printSyntaxTree($$); }
  ;

E : E arith E { $$ = newOpNode($2, $1, $3); }
  | "(" E ")" { $$ = $2; }
  | "-" E %prec UMINUS { $$ = newOpNode(UMINUS, 0, $2); }
  | id { $$ = newIDNode($1); }
  | INT { $$ = newIntNode($1); }
  | FLOAT { $$ = newDoubleNode($1); }
  ;

%%

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parser error at %d: %s\n", yylineno, s);
}

int main() {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

My syntax tree:

```
typedef struct SyntaxTree {
    int nodetype;
    union {
        char *id;
        int intval;
        double doubleval;
        char op;
    } value;
    struct SyntaxTree *l;
    struct SyntaxTree *r;
} SyntaxTree;

#define ID_NODE 'I'
#define INT_NODE 'D'
#define DOUBLE_NODE 'F'
#define OP_NODE '+'
#define UMINUS_NODE 'M'

SyntaxTree * newOpNode(char *op, SyntaxTree *l, SyntaxTree *r){
    SyntaxTree *node = malloc(sizeof(SyntaxTree));
    if(!node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of space\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->nodetype = op;
    node->value.op = op;
    node->l = l;
    node->r = r;
    printf("added new op node");
    return node;
}

SyntaxTree * newDoubleNode(double value){
    SyntaxTree *node = malloc(sizeof(SyntaxTree));
    if(!node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of space\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->nodetype = DOUBLE_NODE;
    node->value.doubleval = value;
    node->l = node->r = NULL;
    printf("added new double node");
    return node;
}

SyntaxTree * newIntNode(int value){
    SyntaxTree *node = malloc(sizeof(SyntaxTree));
    if(!node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of space\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->nodetype = INT_NODE;
    node->value.intval = value;
    node->l = node->r = NULL;
    printf("added new int node");
    return node;
}

SyntaxTree * newIDNode(char* id){
    SyntaxTree *node = malloc(sizeof(SyntaxTree));
    if(!node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of space\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->nodetype = ID_NODE;
    node->value.id = strdup(id);
    node->l = node->r = NULL;
    printf("added new id node");
    return node;
}

void printSyntaxTree(SyntaxTree *head) {
    if (head != NULL) {
        printSyntaxTree(head->l);

        switch (head->nodetype) {
            case ID_NODE:
                printf("Identifier : %s ", head->value.id);
                break;
            case INT_NODE:
                printf("Integer : %d ", head->value.intval);
                break;
            case DOUBLE_NODE:
                printf("Double : %f ", head->value.doubleval);
                break;
            case OP_NODE:
                printf("Arithmetic Operator ");
                break;
            case '=':
                printf("Assignment Operator ");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown node type: %c ", head->nodetype);
                break;
        }

        printSyntaxTree(head->r);
    }
}
```

When I run my parser,

```
a=a+b

Identifier : a Assignment Operator

Identifier : a added new id nodeArithmetic Operator

Identifier : b added new id node
a=0

Identifier : a added new op nodeadded new id nodeadded new op nodeParser error at 2: syntax error, unexpected id, expecting $end
```

It gives `expecting $end` for whatever I give in the 2nd line.

I use `bison` for `yacc` and `flex` for `lex` with syntaxtree structure.

What is `$end`? How do I give it?

I surfed SO and other sites for answers but still no use. I even searched [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755874/why-is-bison-expecting-end-after-the-first-token) but it ended in vain

Comment: Please ask only one question per question, and take care to reduce your problem to the smallest possible program. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is bison expecting $end after the first token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755874/why-is-bison-expecting-end-after-the-first-token)

Comment: @tripleee I didn't call yylex()

Comment: Nonetheless, we would expect you to search before asking, and probably note that yours is different from another question about roughly the same topic. Again, please read the links I provided and [edit] accordingly.

Comment: @tripleee I searched enough before asking but couldn't find anything relatable. that's why raised this question. I even went through the link which u provided

Comment: And still you are asking two unrelated questions, with a wall of code? If you think the help pages are unclear on these points, perhaps bring it up on [meta] separately. In the meantime, you will be _much_ more likely to get an answer if you can pare this down to, say, less than 30 lines of code, and ask a single question.

Comment: @tripleee edited my question. It now asks a single question with less code

Comment: You mention a second line, but your grammar only admits the form `id assign E`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of problems in your grammar. You've defined +/- as left associative tokens but do not use them in the grammar. You appear to have consumed those  token in arith that has no associativity.

You need to add +/- to your grammar separately from arith.
You also need to make uminus right associative.